# How should I pronounce 'taunting'?

Tags: pronunciation

I wonder how I should pronounce the vowel in 'taunting.'

I thought it was [ɔ] sound as in 'haunt,'

> Cambridge Dictionary. It says "UK /tɔːnt/ US /tɑːnt/".

but heard many times that some people in the United States pronounce it [au] as in 'mount' or [a] as in 'god', so I am so confused.

Comment: Daunt, haunt, flaunt, saunter, lawn, dawn, yawn...

Comment: Which dictionary did you consult?  What did it say?

Comment: @JamesK Cambridge Dictionary. It says "UK  /tɔːnt/ US  /tɑːnt/". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/taunt

Comment: Well that answers the question doesn't it.  The pronunciation in the US is different from in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

This is the result of the **cot/caught merger.** Some English speakers (including about half of Americans) pronounce [ɔ] as [ɑ], thus pronouncing "cot" and "caught" identically. This explains why "taunting" can be pronounced with either sound: the usual sound would be [ɔ] but those with the cot-caught merger would say [ɑ].

Answer (score 0):

I live in the US. I pronounce the first vowel in *taunting* the same as the vowel in *lawn* or *pawn*.
I've never heard it with either of the other two sounds you mention.
This dictionary link shows the pronunciation:
[Merriam-Webster *taunt*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taunting)

Comment: MW shows two pronunciations: ˈtȯnt  and ˈtänt, which I think are  [ɔ] and  [a] respectively.